# Go to the Beginning of String in "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application written in VB.Net where I call a dialog window  that lets a user select a file or folder to copy. In that window I have text pre-populated in the file name field as an informational type of message to the user. However the text is so long that it only shows the last bit of it, so I need a way to reset the cursor position to the first character in the string. I also have the text highlighted by default so that the user can just begin typing to overwrite it. Here's what I have so far-
`pushLocationBox1.SelectAll()`
`cursorPosition = pushLocationBox1.SelectionStart`

I think the "cursorPosition = pushLocationBox1.SelectionStart" is a good start at getting the location I need to point the cursor to, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It _sounds_ like you're abusing the Common Dialog functionality - if it is a normal common dialog, people should be aware of why it's being opened without an additional prompt needing to be present

Comment: @JamesThorpe I kind of am in the sense that I'm using a custom class that allows the user to select either a file OR a folder at a time. Because of this the text in the file text box reads "When selecting a directory, select the directory and hit 'open' twice.".

Comment: I use something similar like you but just 3 words (beause the size of window) , in Dialog Window is a Windows 7 (8.1)  Open Folder or Select FIle and I dont think you have control to cursor position ..

Comment: or try : pushLocationBox1.Select(0, 0)

Comment: and pushLocationBox1.Focus() will place the cursor at the beginning of the line. Try it ! :)

Comment: Have you tried overriding the OpenFileDialog class to make your own custom control, and then in the OnFormShown you can set the cursor position in the filename TextBox?